# Autoformat of single statement blocks to one line with braces on same line

Tags: resharper, autoformatting, visual-studio-2015

Just recently, I suspect after a ReSharper update, VS2015 has started with an auto-format that is blood-curdling:

If I type e.g:

```
using(var x = new Disposable())
{
...
}
```

as soon as I type the closing brace, it gets formatted to an ugly bloody single line:

```
using(var x = new Disposable()) { ... }
```

I have checked every formatting setting in VS and R# and can find nothing except 'Autoformat after }' in the VS settings, and have naturally turned it off. Does anyone have any idea what setting or device or demon is doing this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To disable auto-formatting on closing brace in R#, please untick `ReSharper | Options | Environment | Editor | Editor Behavior | Auto-format on closing brace`
2. To disable moving braces to a single line with using statement, please select "Do not change" or "Force line breaks" here `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping | Preserve Existing Formatting | Break line in a block with a single statement`

Comment: Thank you so much. You have saved me from certain insanity, because as soon as R# puts things on a single line, the own R# StyleCop extension complains about it.

Comment: Thanks. Also, this works for if statement blocks with a single statement in them as well (no braces) - which resharper generates out of other refactorings like "Invert If".  Previously, R# used to put the formatted statement right next to if.